# Is there a way to search for multiple times when running a query in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I'm extremely new to SQL!  Honestly, other than online coursework for other focuses and surfing the internet, I'm extremely new to all of this.  I've been working on the Google Data Analytics Career Certificate and am working on the capstone.  I can't seem to find the right syntax to get a complete list all in one place of what I'm looking for when it comes to times for this particular dataset.

Just because I wanted to get the information to use to continue working, I did a search for every single time from 12:00 AM to 11:00 PM to get my results one at a time.  However, I would really like to get the right syntax to get them all in one place if possible.

Here is my current query to get one at a time:

```
SELECT AVG(Step_Total) AS Average_Steps

 FROM `analyticscapstone-378406.fitbit_data.hourly_steps`

WHERE Hour = '12:00 AM'
```

[Screenshot of my attempt and result with current query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAA62.png)

I tried every way I could think of with what literal experience I have but could not get them all into one list neatly displayed in the results.  My attempts resulted in one at a time or a dreaded syntax error.

Any help on this be would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to the StackOverflow community but look forward to learning from everyone and hopefully being able to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly

You need to use [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) clause and use `Hour` column to group all the averages with respect to each Hour value.

```
SELECT Hour, AVG(Step_Total) AS Average_Steps
FROM `analyticscapstone-378406.fitbit_data.hourly_steps`
GROUP BY Hour
```

Comment: You understood my problem perfectly!  Thank you so much for your help!